# When to use forward(), include() and sendRedirect()?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I am new to Java EE env, i read a lot of courses to get the difference between those three methods but most of them contains definitions ... i need a **concrete examples** **when to use each one of these three methods ?**

- sendRedirect()
- forward()
- include()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

few  below point may help you to understand when to use which method:

**sendRedirect()**

> This works at client side.
>   It always sends a new request.
>   It can be used within and outside the server
>   Example: response.sendRedirect("servlet2");

**forward()**

> The forward() method works at server side.
>   It sends the same request and response objects to another servlet.
>   It can work within the server only.
>   Example: request.getRequestDispacher("servlet2").forward(request,response);

**include()**

> The include method is used to includes a file during the translation phase.
>   A good example of include directive is including a common header and footer with multiple pages of content.
>       Or Loading same login page when entered invalid login details

Answer (score 4):

When to use this methods.

**Send Redirect**

> when you want client to initiate completely new Request which does not completely depend on the previous operation.

**Forward**

> this is server side processing and there is no indication on the client side.
>   there are two condition
>   One : Request is completely processed and forward to a tempting  technology like JSP to generate view.
>   Two : Request is need to be further processed by another Servlet and that servlet will decide the final output.

**Include**

> This can be used for sending request to another servlet for additional processing but the final output is to be decided by the current servlet.

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `response.sendRedirect("servlet2")` method will redirect you to the other servlet. i.e `servlet1 --> servlet2`.

> you can view  your url which indicates the servlet2 url.

---

The `request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2").include(request, response)` method will include the servlet2 page along with the servlet1 page. i.e **In servlet1 itself you can view both the servlet's**.

> you can notice the url that shows the url of servlet1.

---

The `request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2").forward(request, response)` method will display the servlet2 page in the servlet1 page. i.e **In servlet1 itself you are viewing  the servlet2**. It is just Like Forwarding the servlet's.

> you can notice the url that shows the url of servlet1.

---

In general Request Dispatcher belongs to HttpServletRequest & sendRedirect belong to HttpServletResponse
dispatcher is maintained at client side
sendRedirect is maintained at Server side.